# Where are the subtanks located?

Tags: mega-man-zx

I'm currently stuck in *[Mega Man ZX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man_ZX)* with a bit of a dilemma. I have already reached the final area of the game, but I only have one subtank (the one from the Power Plant), which is proving to be very little in the midst of 10 almost consecutive boss battles. All my exploring has only uncovered data disk after data disk and no subtanks. Where can I find them?

Comment: @Badp - Is a secret fundamentally different from a spoiler?

Comment: @sean while it's great you're trying to improve the site, flooding the front page with minor edits isn't conducive to that. Please keep the bulk editing to a minimum and discuss any mass cleanup project first on [our meta-discussion site](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com) to gain consensus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtank locations can be found in section **`mi01`** of [this](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/800/800589p1.html) guide:

> **Subtank I, Area E-4:** Below the
>   spinning gears and to the right.
>
> **Subtank II, Area A-2:** Above the tunnel
>   with razor blade enemies, and to the
>   left.
>
> **Subtank III, Area  K-1:** After the
>   first mini boss, fall down and head to
>   the right. Use *Biometal Model HX* to go
>   upwards until you find a computer
>   terminal. Use the terminal and head
>   back to Area 
>   **`K-4`**, and go right until
>   the path splits. Use *Model FX's* charge
>   attack to break the blocks on the
>   upper path. Head through the hidden
>   door to unlock area **`K-1`**, where the
>   subtank is located.
>
> **Subtank IV, Area X-1:** Complete the
>   *Find the Aid Kit* sidequests.

Comment: Please do not just link sites without providing a summery.  Its ok to repeat the same thing and link where you got it from, but just providing a link is not good.

Comment: links can go stale.  The purpose of this site is to collect information.  Linking to another site is just collecting links, if that memory gets freed: SEGFAULT